# Throws Nullpointer exception when calls parent class method from child class In JAVA

Tags: java, inheritance

This is Parent class

```
public class RequestDTO implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private String paymentProvider;
    private Boolean isEncrypt;

    public RequestDTO() {
    }

    public RequestDTO(String paymentProvider,
            Boolean isEncrypt) {
        super();
        this.paymentProvider = paymentProvider;
        this.isEncrypt = isEncrypt;
    }

   

    public void setPaymentProvider(String paymentProvider) {
        this.paymentProvider = paymentProvider;
    }

   
    
    public Boolean getIsEncrypt() {
        return isEncrypt;
    }

    public void setIsEncrypt(Boolean isEncrypt) {
        if (isEncrypt == null) {
            this.isEncrypt = false;
        } else {
            this.isEncrypt = isEncrypt;
        }
    }
}
```

Below is child class

```
   public class CardDetailsDTO extends RequestDTO {
    
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        
        private String cardNumber;
        private String expiryDate;
        private String cardHolderName;
        private String cardType;
        private String cardIssueDate;
        private String cardIssueNo;
      
    
        private String modifyDummyCardNumber(String cardNum) {
            String dummyCardNumber ;
            if (cardNum != null && !cardNum.isEmpty() && this.getIsEncrypt() != true) {
                dummyCardNumber = "************" + cardNum.substring(12);
                return dummyCardNumber;
            } else {
                return "********";
            }
         }
    
        public String getCardNumber() {
            return cardNumber;
        }
      
        public void setCardNumber(String cardNumber) {
            this.cardNumber = cardNumber;
        }
        public String getExpiryDate() {
            return expiryDate;
        }
        public void setExpiryDate(String expiryDate) {
            this.expiryDate = expiryDate;
        }
        public String getCardHolderName() {
            return cardHolderName;
        }
        public void setCardHolderName(String cardHolderName) {
            this.cardHolderName = cardHolderName;
        }
        public String getCardType() {
            return cardType;
        }
        public void setCardType(String cardType) {
            this.cardType = cardType;
        }
        public String getCardIssueDate() {
            return cardIssueDate;
        }
        public void setCardIssueDate(String cardIssueDate) {
            this.cardIssueDate = cardIssueDate;
        }
        public String getCardIssueNo() {
            return cardIssueNo;
        }
        public void setCardIssueNo(String cardIssueNo) {
            this.cardIssueNo = cardIssueNo;
        }
@Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        builder.append("CardDetailsDTO [expiryDate=");
        builder.append(expiryDate);
        builder.append(", cardHolderName=");
        builder.append(cardHolderName);
        builder.append(", cardType=");
        builder.append(cardType);
        builder.append(", cardIssueDate=");
        builder.append(cardIssueDate);
        builder.append(", cardIssueNo=");
        builder.append(cardIssueNo);
        builder.append(", dummyCardNumber=");
        builder.append(modifyDummyCardNumber(getCardNumber()));
        builder.append("]");
        return builder.toString();
    }
    }
```

when I called

> modifyDummyCardNumber

method inside child class toString method it throws null pointer exception because I called this.getIsEncrypt() inside modifyDummyCardNumber method if statement as showing above ,but when I sout the isEncrypt value from the parent class it shows as "true",
How to use the parent class variable value in child class?

Comment: Your class CardDetailsDTO  is not extending the parent class RequestDTO  ?

Comment: Use `super.getIsEncrypt()` instead of `this.getIsEncrypt()`

Comment: No.. It extends . Look again "public class CardDetailsDTO extends RequestDTO"

Comment: @lucumt will try.

Comment: the call to the method looks correct, can you show us how you use `modifyDummyCardNumber` and where you set `isEncrypt`? Also i think you need brackets around `this.getIsEncrypt() != true`, since i think he will work from left to right, so it compares everything else first and then looks if it is not false. But i am not 100% sure about that.

Comment: @user11670196 I called method inside the child class toString method,                    Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        builder.append("CardDetailsDTO 
        builder.append(", dummyCardNumber=");
        builder.append(modifyDummyCardNumber(getCardNumber()));
        builder.append("]");
        return builder.toString();
    }

Comment: @lucumt did not work with super also

Comment: because `isEncrypt` is private in the RequestDTO class, you'd need a getter for it if you plan on using it in the subclasses. Or making it `protected`

Comment: Please provide a stack trace and a code sample calling the method where the error occurs. Also, why are you using `Boolean ` instead of `bool`, and why not `if (! getIsEncrypt() `?

Comment: @Shark already im calling the getter method for isEncrypt. "this.getIsEncrypt() != true"

Comment: But on a second look, nothing is really setting the `isEncrypt` to anything, and due to it being `Boolean` it starts off as `null`. the child class should invoke the `setIsEncrypt` method in it's constructor most probably.

Comment: @dasitha that getter will just return `null` due to it never being set to anything. (at least "nowhere from the code you posted")

Comment: @daniu im calling the method inside the child class toString method, error is                       "java.lang.NullPointerException
upa_tomcat    |     at com.noetic.dto.elavon.CardDetailsDTO.modifyDummyCardNumber(CardDetailsDTO.java:28)
"

Comment: @Shark im initializing the DTO via rest end point , when I sout the requestDTO it shows isEncrypt value as true.

Comment: I tested it on my pc and it works fine, as long as as i set isEncrypted before the call. That is once again why i wanted you show us the rest of the code, especially the part where you set isEncrypted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is one problem in this code: the class `RequestDTO` has a constructor without arguments, which means that it can throw `NullPointerException` if the variables of this class are not defined before using this constructor (this might be why it throws you `NullPointerException`).

You can also assign default values on the declaration of each variable of the class.

Anyway this code shouldn't throw any `NullPointerException` if the variable `isEncrypt` is assigned to any value.

Comment: when I remove "&& this.getIsEncrypt() != true" from dummycardnumber, the code execute successfully.  will try without default constructor .

Comment: "the method modifyDummyCardNumber is private and it is not executed by CardDetailsDTO" - yes it is?

Answer (score 1):

Since `isEncrypt` is never set, it is `null` by default.

The term `getIsEncrypt()!  = false` tries to unbox the `null` as `bool`, which fails.

Do

```
public class RequestDTO implements Serializable {
    // ...
    private boolean isEncrypt;
    // ...
}
```

and, while you're at it

```
if (cardNum != null && !cardNum.isEmpty() && !this.getIsEncrypt()) {
```

Comment: I am not sure if isEncrypt is never set, since he says it is true if he prints it. Also he did not show us the part of the code that is using the class yet.

Comment: @user11670196 Yes, it's a prime example why [mcve] is needed.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid this kind of errors change the type of isEncrypted field to `boolean`(primitive type).

Comment: this is java. Boolean is a primitiv type and bool does not even exist

Comment: With capital B it is not primitive